# is this a valid html- an a tag inside text?

Tags: html, validation

```
    <li> text text  (  <a href="example.com">text</a>  )   </li>
```

I don't know it confuses me, an a tag inside li tag between 2 parentheses ?

Comment: the parentheses  are there only to make it look like this  "text (link)". It has nothing to with html syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Yes:

```html
<li> text text  (  <a href="example.com">text</a>  )   </li>
```

If not, you wouldn't be able to do things like

```html
<ul>
  <li>this is a list item <a href="#">with an inline link</a></li>
 </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Html is a very flexible language and some bad codes works that you think that will never works! But your code has no problem.

And you could write that in this way:

```
<li> text text    <a href="example.com">(text)</a> </li>
```